# Not able to connect to SQLDatabase after web app has been deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, sql-server, heroku, odbc, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a webpage built with flask for my company which requires me to connect to their SQL database. I am using SQLalchemy create_engine() function to create the connection. When developing this locally everything was working great, but after deploying to Heroku I have been faced with errors I have been spending all day trying to resolve. All functionalities of the live Heroku app work, but break when connection is attempted.

My connection is created like this.

```
 def connect(self):
        #Arguments for connection
        DRIVER_NAME = 'SQL SERVER'
        SERVER_NAME = 'SQLDATA'
        DATABASE_NAME = 'Rehab'

        #Connecting paramaters
        connection_string = f"""
            DRIVER={{{DRIVER_NAME}}};
            SERVER={SERVER_NAME};
            DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};
            Trust_Connection = yes;
            uid = ###########;  <--- this is correct just hiding
            pwd = ##########;   <--- this is correct just hiding
        """
   
        connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
     
        engine = create_engine(connection_url)
        return engine
```

When I run this function Locally I am faced with no issues.

The errors presented to me by heroku is

````
2022-06-14T21:29:20.172377+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
2022-06-14T21:29:20.172377+00:00 app[web.1]: return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2022-06-14T21:29:20.172377+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
2022-06-14T21:29:20.172378+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2022-06-14T21:29:20.172378+00:00 app[web.1]: pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL SERVER' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")```
````

Any help would be so appreciated! Thank you to anybody who takes the time. I apologize if the question is unclear I am new to asking stackoverflow questions. If you need any clarifications I will do my best to hastily reply!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Heroku instance didn't have SQL SERVER driver installed.

Maybe try installing SQL SERVER driver on the Heroku instance

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am admittedly pretty new to this and can't find many resources online on how to install SQL SERVER  on my Heroku. How would I go about this?

Comment: Sorry, I am not too familiar with how to set up Heroku to help you on this one :/